# MongoDB - Aggregate get specific objects in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How can I get only objects in the `sales` array matching with **2021-10-14** date ?
My aggregate query currently returns all objects of the sales array if at least one is matching.

**Dataset Documents**

```
{
    "name": "#0",
    "sales": [{
        "date": "2021-10-14",
        "price": 3.69,
    },{
        "date": "2021-10-15",
        "price": 2.79,
    }]
},
{
    "name": "#1",
    "sales": [{
        "date": "2021-10-14",
        "price": 1.5,
    }]
}
```

**Aggregate**

```
{
  $match: {
    sales: {
      $elemMatch: {
        date: '2021-10-14',
      },
    },
  },
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: 0,
    data: {
      $push: '$sales',
    },
  },
},
{
  $project: {
    data: {
      $reduce: {
        input: '$data',
        initialValue: [],
        in: {
          $setUnion: ['$$value', '$$this'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

**Result**

```
{"date": "2021-10-14","price": 3.69},
{"date": "2021-10-15","price": 2.79},
{"date": "2021-10-14","price": 1.5}
```

**Result Expected**

```
{"date": "2021-10-14","price": 3.69},
{"date": "2021-10-14","price": 1.5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to use a [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) or [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) pipeline which takes in an expression that gives you the resulting document filtered using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) (or [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) from the `sales` array:

```
[
    { $match: { 'sales.date': '2021-10-14' } },
    { $replaceWith: {
       $arrayElemAt: [
           {
               $filter: {
                   input: '$sales',
                   cond: { $eq: ['$$this.date', '2021-10-14'] }
               }
           },
          0 
       ]
   } }
]
```

OR

```
[
    { $match: { 'sales.date': '2021-10-14' } },
    { $replaceRoot: {
       newRoot: {
           $arrayElemAt: [
               {
                   $filter: {
                       input: '$sales',
                       cond: { $eq: ['$$this.date', '2021-10-14'] }
                   }
               },
              0 
           ]
       }
    } }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Iud7a9ey-Mx)

Comment: if sales array contains >1 members with that date 1 of them is kept. Maybe this is what you need but check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TRzOqtciKF0)

Answer (score 2):

How about using $unwind:

```
.aggregate([
{$match: {    sales: {$elemMatch: {date: '2021-10-14'}    }  }},
{$unwind: '$sales'},
{$match: {'sales.date': '2021-10-14'}},
{$project: {date: '$sales.date', price: '$sales.price', _id: 0}}
])
```

This will separate the sales into different documents, each containing only one sale, and allow you to match conditions easily.
See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In `$project` stage, you need `$filter` operator with `input` as `$reduce` operator to filter the documents.

```
{
  $project: {
    data: {
      $filter: {
        input: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$data",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $setUnion: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this"
              ],
            }
          }
        },
        cond: {
          $eq: [
            "$$this.date",
            "2021-10-14"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HGozcNhOTxl)